Deployment Error: npm run build fails for Next.js 15 on Vercel
I am developing an app using Next.js 15 and trying to deploy it on Vercel. However, during the build process, I encounter several errors and warnings related to TypeScript, ESLint, and React.
Here are the details of my build log:
[11:53:54.837] Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1
[11:53:54.999] Cloning github.com/M3nnoun/fastQuizz (Branch: master, Commit: 5582369)
[11:53:55.014] Skipping build cache, deployment was triggered without cache.
[11:53:55.499] Cloning completed: 499.492ms
[11:53:55.816] Running "vercel build"
[11:53:56.290] Vercel CLI 39.1.1
[11:53:57.344] Installing dependencies...
[11:54:01.219] npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
[11:54:01.938] npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
[11:54:02.118] npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
[11:54:03.625] npm warn deprecated @humanwhocodes/config-array@0.13.0: Use @eslint/config-array instead
[11:54:03.695] npm warn deprecated @humanwhocodes/object-schema@2.0.3: Use @eslint/object-schema instead
[11:54:06.766] npm warn deprecated eslint@8.57.1: This version is no longer supported. Please see https://eslint.org/version-support for other options.
[11:54:15.764] 
[11:54:15.766] added 605 packages in 18s
[11:54:15.766] 
[11:54:15.767] 143 packages are looking for funding
[11:54:15.767]   run `npm fund` for details
[11:54:15.792] Detected Next.js version: 15.0.3
[11:54:15.799] Running "npm run build"
[11:54:15.934] 
[11:54:15.934] > skeleton@0.1.0 build
[11:54:15.934] > next build
[11:54:15.934] 
[11:54:16.628] Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
[11:54:16.629] This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
[11:54:16.629] You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
[11:54:16.629] https://nextjs.org/telemetry
[11:54:16.629] 
[11:54:16.735]    ▲ Next.js 15.0.3
[11:54:16.736] 
[11:54:16.764]    Creating an optimized production build ...
[11:54:52.040]  ✓ Compiled successfully
[11:54:52.046]    Linting and checking validity of types ...
[11:54:57.557] 
[11:54:57.558] Failed to compile.
[11:54:57.558] 
[11:54:57.559] ./app/(root)/quizz/[slug]/page.tsx
[11:54:57.559] 39:21  Error: Unexpected any. Specify a different type.  @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
[11:54:57.559] 
[11:54:57.559] ./app/actions.ts
[11:54:57.559] 67:19  Error: Unexpected any. Specify a different type.  @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
[11:54:57.560] 
[11:54:57.560] ./app/utils/analyze.ts
[11:54:57.560] 3:10  Error: 'average' is defined but never used.  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
[11:54:57.560] 
[11:54:57.561] ./components/correct-pie.tsx
[11:54:57.561] 51:11  Warning: The 'desktopData' array makes the dependencies of useMemo Hook (at line 62) change on every render. To fix this, wrap the initialization of 'desktopData' in its own useMemo() Hook.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[11:54:57.561] 51:11  Warning: The 'desktopData' array makes the dependencies of useMemo Hook (at line 64) change on every render. To fix this, wrap the initialization of 'desktopData' in its own useMemo() Hook.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[11:54:57.561] 
[11:54:57.561] ./components/cta.tsx
[11:54:57.561] 17:79  Error: `'` can be escaped with `&apos;`, `&lsquo;`, `&#39;`, `&rsquo;`.  react/no-unescaped-entities
[11:54:57.562] 
[11:54:57.562] ./components/fileUploader.tsx
[11:54:57.562] 16:10  Error: 'error' is assigned a value but never used.  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
[11:54:57.562] 17:10  Error: 'response' is assigned a value but never used.  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
[11:54:57.562] 63:21  Error: Unexpected any. Specify a different type.  @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
[11:54:57.562] 
[11:54:57.562] ./components/qrCodeSection.tsx
[11:54:57.563] 3:10  Error: 'useState' is defined but never used.  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
[11:54:57.563] 
[11:54:57.563] ./components/quizz-form.tsx
[11:54:57.563] 134:63  Error: `'` can be escaped with `&apos;`, `&lsquo;`, `&#39;`, `&rsquo;`.  react/no-unescaped-entities
[11:54:57.563] 135:56  Error: `'` can be escaped with `&apos;`, `&lsquo;`, `&#39;`, `&rsquo;`.  react/no-unescaped-entities
[11:54:57.564] 
[11:54:57.564] ./components/testimonials.tsx
[11:54:57.564] 68:9  Warning: Using `<img>` could result in slower LCP and higher bandwidth. Consider using `<Image />` from `next/image` to automatically optimize images. This may incur additional usage or cost from your provider. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element  @next/next/no-img-element
[11:54:57.564] 
[11:54:57.564] ./components/ui/chart.tsx
[11:54:57.564] 6:3  Error: 'NameType' is defined but never used.  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
[11:54:57.565] 7:3  Error: 'Payload' is defined but never used.  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
[11:54:57.565] 8:3  Error: 'ValueType' is defined but never used.  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
[11:54:57.565] 77:7  Error: '_' is defined but never used.  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
[11:54:57.565] 
[11:54:57.565] ./components/ui/hero-video-dialog.tsx
[11:54:57.565] 86:9  Warning: Using `<img>` could result in slower LCP and higher bandwidth. Consider using `<Image />` from `next/image` to automatically optimize images. This may incur additional usage or cost from your provider. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element  @next/next/no-img-element
[11:54:57.566] 
[11:54:57.566] ./components/ui/marquee.tsx
[11:54:57.566] 10:18  Error: Unexpected any. Specify a different type.  @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
[11:54:57.566] 
[11:54:57.566] ./components/ui/sparkles-text.tsx
[11:54:57.567] 105:6  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'sparklesCount'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[11:54:57.567] 
[11:54:57.567] info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/eslint#disabling-rules
[11:54:57.611] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
[11:54:58.351] 

Here’s my package.json if it helps:
{
  "name": "skeleton",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/firestore": "^4.7.5",
    "@google/generative-ai": "^0.21.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-accordion": "^1.2.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-avatar": "^1.1.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.1.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-navigation-menu": "^1.2.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-radio-group": "^1.2.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-select": "^2.1.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-toast": "^1.2.2",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "embla-carousel-react": "^8.3.1",
    "firebase": "^11.0.2",
    "formidable": "^3.5.2",
    "lucide-react": "^0.456.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "next": "15.0.3",
    "next-qrcode": "^2.5.1",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "framer-motion": "^11.11.17",
    "recharts": "^2.13.3",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.5.4",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/formidable": "^3.4.5",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.12",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "15.0.3",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}

I haven't attempted to fix these issues yet, as I'm unsure of the best place to start. Any guidance on how to resolve these errors and successfully deploy my app would be greatly appreciated!
